# How to add a Line Break inside Message

Tags: node.js, reactjs

How do I add a `<br>` to my message using node.js?

```
const Register = (req, res) => {
    const first_name = req.body.first_name
    const last_name = req.body.last_name
    const email = req.body.email
    const one_time_token = req.body.one_time_token

    return res.send({
        success: false,
        message: `<p><b>Generated Access Code:</b> ${one_time_token}</p>`
    })
}
```

Result:

```
Generated Access Code: XXXX-XXXXXX-XXXX
```

Expected:

```
line 1: Generated Access Code:
 line 2: XXXX-XXXXXX-XXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by line break since you illustration of what you expect is the same as what you get ...
But if you wish to have something like: Expected: Generated Access Code: (on one line)
XXXX-XXXXXX-XXXX (on the next line) try using 
 tag

Comment: When I try to use <br> I will get an output:


<p><b>Generated Access Code:</b><br/>3G8G-6X3P0G-1X8G</p>

Comment: i wanted to have
line 1: Generated Access Code:
line 2: XXXX-XXXXXX-XXXX

Comment: What do you mean by using tag @chris may you please give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add the `<br>` HTML element in your message?

```
message: `<p><b>Generated Access Code:</b><br/>${one_time_token}</p>`
```

Comment: When I try to add your suggestion: 

Result: <p><b>Generated Access Code:</b><br/>3G8G-6X3P0G-1X8G</p>